# Mobile HTML input textbox hide soft keypad on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search text box that onsubmit event will get search results using AJAX. So I am using the same page to refresh/update the search results.

But, on mobile devices with both chrome and safari, the soft-keyboard does not hide on submit event.

How can I hide the soft-keypad for mobile only? (FYI - I tried to force onblur but it affects the desktop layout, im using bootstrap responsive layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this for mobile is to blur your search text box.

```
OnSubmit
$('#search_text_box').blur();
```

It will hide the virtual keyboard.

Comment: thank you, i guess there is no other way to do it! I got to write a function to blur only for mobile devices....thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem your having with your desktop layout? Shouldn't that be the question? :)